# Gmail not expanding to 100% width only on iOS

Tags: ios, email, gmail, width, litmus

been struggling with this issue for a bit now and its really bugging me. Basically I have some email templates that I've been working on, they work fine on all clients (Litmus tests) except for Gmail specifically on iOS, Android works fine. The issue I'm having is that I want all my tables to me 100% width so they're all the same size, however gmail resizes the tables seemingly based off the content inside.

Heres a section of my code:

```
<tr class="module bg-white" style="background-color:#fff;color:#23282b">
<td>
    <table class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" width="100%"
        style="margin:0 auto;width:100%!important;max-width:600px!important">
        <tr>
            <td class="card-wrapper" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 15px 10px">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="card-content bg-white border-lightgray"
                            style="padding:30px 20px 20px;background-color:#fff;color:#23282b;border:solid 1px #eee">
                            <h2
                                style="font-family:GTAmerica-Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0 0 20px;font-size:18px;font-weight:700;line-height:22px">
                                YOUR DELIVERY DETAILS</h2>
                            <table class="delivery-details" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
                                role="presentation" width="100%"
                                style="width:100%!important;max-width:600px!important">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-right:8.5px;padding-left:0">
                                        <h3
                                            style="font-family:GTAmerica-Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0 0 15px;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;line-height:22px">
                                            Delivery Service</h3>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-right:0">
                                        <p
                                            style="font-family:GTAmerica-Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0 0 10px;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:15px;line-height:22px">
                                            Next Day</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-right:8.5px;padding-left:0">
                                        <h3
                                            style="font-family:GTAmerica-Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0 0 15px;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;line-height:22px">
                                            Delivery Address</h3>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-right:0">
                                        <p
                                            style="font-family:GTAmerica-Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0 0 10px;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:15px;line-height:22px">
                                            Fake Name <br>Fake House <br>Fake Street
                                            <br>Fake Town <br>UK <br>Fake Postcode</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

On my phone it looks like this:

[Email Result on iOS 15 gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijahh.jpg)

Is there any way to fix this? On every other client it expands to 100% no issue, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like this might be due to [this bug](https://mosaico.io/email-client-tricks/gmail-android-tries-to-shrink-your-email/), where Gmail adds a `.munged` class to `<table>`s and `<td>`s with a `width:auto!important`.

A solution would be to add a `min-width:100%` to each `<table>` and `<td>` potentially impacted.

Comment: I've seen a bunch of stuff like this, I experience no issues on Android though. I will try your suggestions

Comment: Thank you this saved hours of frustration!